Can OpenCV precompute the ResizeFilter to speed up resize operations like Intel IPPI?
I used OpenCV to resize an image (1400*750, U8C1). It took about 10ms, which is a bit slow.
I found that Intel IPPI can precompute the ResizeFilter and then perform the resize operation much faster. When the same resize operation is performed the next time, the calculation of ResizeFilter can be avoided.
So, OpenVC can precompute the ResizeFilter to speed up resize operations like Intel IPPI.
I did not find any information about the ResizeFilter in OpenCV document.

Not sure how IPP does it, but opencv has a cv::remap function which can be used with precomputed maps.

@Micka Thank you for your comment, I'll try it out.
